Is it recommended to use PCA to group features into categories?
I will give a dummy example. Let's say you're hired by a trucking company to predict how many years their trucks will last for. They have an inventory of 200 trucks and the company has 80 features that they require you to use as part of your modelling. Assume that these are already preprocessed and ready to do. In addition, they want to look at variable importance to determine where to focus their efforts such that their trucks last longer.
We have a very wide dataset here, clearly. Now on to my proposal:

Let's say we can categorize these 80 features into 6 logical groups (eg. maintenance, vehicle type, etc). Do so.
Run PCA on each group to attain the first component, and remove the original features. We're left with a (200, 6) dataset.
Split the data, create your regression model, tune parameters, yada yada yada.
Run SHAP on the features.

This technique avoids the problem of SHAP features being challenging to understand since each component isn't composed of every original feature, just it's group's features. The obvious drawback I can see is we're clearly losing out on some variance within the original dataset, and the amount would depend on how much coverage each first component provides.
Is this a recommended approach? I can't find literature one way or the other.


The obvious drawback I can see is we're clearly losing out on some variance within the original dataset, and the amount would depend on how much coverage each first component provides.

Consider using cross_decomposition.PLSRegression rather than PCA when running dimensionality reduction for a regression task.
PLS regression is like PCA, but it takes the target into account as well, so you will keep more of the target-relevant variance compared to PCA.
PCA only considers preserving $X$ variance, whereas PLS is more like 'preserve the variance of $X$ that is also informative for $Y$'.
This will likely make the first component more useful for predicting $Y$ compared to PCA's first component.

Suppose that each truck is represented by a vector $x^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}^{80}$ for $i=1,2,\dots,200$. We define an invertible linear transformation $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{80 \times 80}$ such that $Q$ can be written as a product $Q = PD$ where $P$ is a random orthogonal matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with nonzero entries. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^{200}$ be the corresponding vector of truck lifetimes. We construct six smooth, mutually orthogonal functions $\phi_1,\phi_2,\ldots,\phi_6 : \mathbb{R}^{80} \to \mathbb{R}$ that each act on a disjoint subset of coordinates in $Qx$, meaning for each $k \in \{1,\dots,6\}$, $\phi_k(Qx) = h_k\!\big((Qx)_{\alpha_k}\big)$ where $\alpha_k$ is the coordinate subset assigned to group $k$ and $h_k$ is any differentiable function. We impose that for any distinct $j,k$, the sets $\alpha_j$ and $\alpha_k$ do not overlap, ensuring no feature belongs to more than one $\phi_k$.
We define a composite map $F : \mathbb{R}^{80} \to \mathbb{R}^6$ by
$$
F(x)
= \bigl(\phi_1(Qx),\,\phi_2(Qx),\,\ldots,\,\phi_6(Qx)\bigr).
$$
We want a latent embedding of each truck’s features into six dimensions that preserves local structure, so we require
$$
\nabla \phi_k(Qx)^\top\,\nabla \phi_j(Qx) = 0 \quad \text{for} \; j \neq k,
$$
i.e. the gradient of each $\phi_k$ is orthogonal to that of every other $\phi_j$. Such a constraint can be enforced by choosing each $\phi_k$ to depend only on the unshared coordinates $(Qx)_{\alpha_k}$. Then we solve
$$
\min_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^m} \, \sum_{i=1}^{200} \bigl(y_i - M(F(x^{(i)});\theta)\bigr)^2,
$$
where $M: \mathbb{R}^6 \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ is any universal function approximator (e.g. a small neural network) parameterized by $\theta$. Each evaluation $M(F(x^{(i)});\theta)$ gives the predicted lifetime of truck $i$. Because the six-dimensional embedding is partitioned by feature group, interpretability emerges from the partial derivatives
$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial u_k}, \quad u_k = \phi_k(Qx),
$$
and the knowledge that $u_k$ only involves coordinates $\alpha_k$. We can then compute, for each truck $i$ and each embedding dimension $k$,
$$
\text{Import}_{i,k} = \left|\frac{\partial M}{\partial u_k}\Bigl(F(x^{(i)});\theta\Bigr)\right|\cdot \left|\nabla \phi_k(Qx^{(i)})\right|.
$$
Summing $\text{Import}_{i,k}$ over $i$ gives the global importance of dimension $k$. To isolate which original features matter most, we examine the Jacobian $\nabla \phi_k(Qx)$ restricted to $\alpha_k$:
$$
\phi_k(Qx) = h_k\!\bigl((Qx)_{\alpha_k}\bigr), \quad
\nabla \phi_k(Qx) = \frac{\partial h_k}{\partial z}\Bigl((Qx)_{\alpha_k}\Bigr) \cdot (Q_{\alpha_k, :}),
$$
so each feature’s contribution depends on both the derivative $\frac{\partial h_k}{\partial z}$ and its corresponding row in $Q_{\alpha_k, :}$. Because $P$ is orthogonal, rotating coordinates with $P$ does not destroy variance but reassigns it among coordinate groups, while the diagonal $D$ can spread or shrink those coordinates to help equalize variance across the six groups. We solve an auxiliary optimization of $Q$ (i.e. updating $P$ and $D$) by maximizing a mutual-information term
$$
\max_{Q} \sum_{k=1}^6 \text{MI}\bigl(\phi_k(Qx),y\bigr)
$$
subject to the orthogonality and diagonal constraints. We can iterate between optimizing $Q$ in that objective and training $M$.
